# How to create MS word like Symbol Insert dialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I am planning to create a insert symbol or alphabet dialog/window in WPF more or less like the one in MS Word. The window should list all fonts with subset dropdown. 
Anyone who can show me a way how to go about developing this. C# is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ribbon control or look for ribbon control samples.Try devcomponent

http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/

or roll your on custom listbox ?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomListBoxLayoutInWPF.aspx

Comment: Thanks abmv. The codeproject article helped me to understand how the UI will be created. But my concern is more on how to get the the alphabets and subsets as a dropdown (as in MS word symbol insert dialog). I think this will be in code behind where I can fetch all characters of a font family and show them on buttons. Again I can see them as per subset dropdown. Any help on this?

Comment: you can use databinding after you get the data as a collection or dataset or whatever