# How do we write code in c# to show insert symbol dialogbox of word and select specific check box symbol?

Tags: c#, ms-word, npoi

From MS Word application, I can insert those symbols from "Wingdings" font, How can I achieve the same, while accessing any word document from C# code.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks In Advance,
Narsingrao Manda

Comment: Hard to understand, what you are trying - what does the 'select specific check box symbol' part from your title mean? I can't find any check boxes in that window.

Comment: "How to create MS word like Symbol Insert dialog in WPF"  is  giving 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. response

Comment: Actually i  want to insert those symbols from "Windings" font, by using c# code

Comment: To 403 Error - well, okay..? :D
Try this one please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665605/2590375

Comment: For "insert windings into word" please read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186960/2590375 No fancy dialog with check boxes, but may give you a hint in the right direction.

Comment: " How to create MS word like Symbol Insert dialog in WPF"  url contains below two urls as a solution but those are returing 403 error
http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomListBoxLayoutInWPF.aspx

Comment: Ah okay ... i got you now. Will remove the duplication vote.

Comment: For "insert windings into word" please read this one: stackoverflow.com/a/17186960/2590375 No fancy dialog with check boxes, but may give you a hint in the right direction. in this mentioned "oWord.Selection.InsertSymbol(254, ref oFont, ref oUnicode,ref oBias);"
May iknow what is oWord is here?

Comment: You really need to improve your web searching skills mate ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertsymbol?view=word-pia